# Rust create a vector of custom struct type

Tags: rust

I'm using [config-rs](https://docs.rs/config/latest/config/) crate. I want to set an [array](https://docs.rs/config/latest/config/enum.ValueKind.html) to a default value in my configuration. I want to use set_default() method from the crate that accepts an argument of type Value<`Array`> https://docs.rs/config/latest/config/builder/struct.ConfigBuilder.html#method.set_default

I'm new to rust and having a hard time as to how I can quickly create a vector<`Value`>

```rust
 let default: Vec<ValueKind>= vec![1,2,3];// Errors 
 let default: Vec<Value>= vec![1,2,3]; // Errros
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a `Vec<T>`, the items have to be of type `T`. Rust does not perform implicit conversions so you need to write a little more code to make this work. It won't even allow implicit conversions between primitive types (Ex: `i32` to `i64`).

For this, you can create a new `Value` or `ValueKind` by using `From`. I know this can be done because the documentation states that [`ValueKind` implements `From<i32>`](https://docs.rs/config/latest/config/enum.ValueKind.html#impl-From%3Ci32%3E-for-ValueKind). The same thing also applies to `Value`, but it is much harder to spot when reading through the [documentation](https://docs.rs/config/latest/config/struct.Value.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-for-Value).

```rust
// Same applies to `Value`.
let default: Vec<ValueKind> = vec![ValueKind::from(1), ValueKind::from(2), ValueKind::from(3)];
```

To make this easier, you also have a few other options. `Into` is implemented automatically for all types implementing `From`, we can replace the lengthy `ValueKind::from(1)` with a shorter `1.into()` call.

```rust
let default: Vec<ValueKind> = vec![1.into(), 2.into(), 3.into()];
```

If you have a lot of values you could also choose to use an iterator to convert an array of values all in one go.

```rust
let default: Vec<ValueKind> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    .into_iter()
    .map(|x| ValueKind::from(x))
    .collect();
```

That being said, <s>I am somewhat surprised the crate authors did not give the option to use `Vec<i32>` as-is (Though I have not checked the documentation on this since I do not know how it is used)</s>*. It is not too difficult to write a generic function which accepts any iterable type like a `Vec`, array, or a bunch of other things, and turn it into `ValueKind` or `Value` as it goes.

```rust
/// Takes some iterable value and turns it into a Vec<ValueKind>.
pub fn to_valuekind<A, T>(values: A) -> Vec<ValueKind>
where
    A: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    ValueKind: From<T>,
{
    values.into_iter().map(|x| ValueKind::from(x)).collect()
}
```

*Looks like it is a restriction on how `set_default` functions. It accepts any `Into<Value>`, but by doing so they can't also implement across `IntoIterator` since it could theoretically cause a conflict if a type implemented both `Into<Value>` and `IntoIterator<T> where T: Into<Value>`.